# fixed header for print not taking full page width

Tags: css, printing

I have a hidden header which is shown when printing a page, but when i try to print it with chrome 40 it's not taking the full width page. why?

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="assets/img/brand.png">
    <div id="title">Departamento de diagnostico por imagenes</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p class="page"></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header{
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position:fixed;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 46px;
}
#title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    /*right: 0;*/
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer .page:after {
    content: counter(page, upper-roman);
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

[image: Problem fixed header not full page width]

**UPDATE**
I changed to position absolute, and it works, it's taking the full width

[image: fixed header but...]

but now I realized that it's not repeating in every page, even with position fixed

[image: page header not repeating]

Also notice the footer with number page, it's wrong centered because of fixed position, but when i change it to absolute it's correct but it goes to the bottom of the content, not of the page, and in the two cases neither repeat in every page

Comment: try to remove `position: fixed` on print stylesheet

Comment: @maioman didn't work

Comment: Could you add the related HTML and CSS for the footer?

Comment: Hm, seems to work out for me. But try to change `position: fixed` to `absolute` in your `#footer` and apply `left: 0; width: 100%;`

Comment: @RamisWachtler yeah it's centered when absolute, but i noticed that when `absolute` header and footer is on top and bottom of content, and when `fixed` both are in only the first page

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fixed` position, add `absolute` instead, and I've also changed the `height` of `#logo` to `100%` instead of `46px`

**SNIPPET**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#header {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#header-table {
  top: 150px;
  /*Change to 0px when supposed to use*/
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
}
#logo-cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#title-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="logo" src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140501181347/creepypasta/images/f/f6/Grumpy_Cat.jpg">
  <div id="title">Departamento de diagnostico por imagenes</div>
</div>
<h3>Display: Table, if your title should be vertically centered</h3>
<div id="header-table">
  <img id="logo-cell" src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140501181347/creepypasta/images/f/f6/Grumpy_Cat.jpg">
  <div id="title-cell">Departamento de diagnostico por imagenes</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution position absolute, I updated the question